# How can i create a list based on a single input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to coding and started with Python to learn myself the basics. Going through codecademy and started with my own simple "junior league team planner" (for my sons soccer team).

I did try to research my problem, but I am unable to find the solution (if you dont know what you are looking for due to lack of expertise things become sort of a catch22 situation)

The problem

Based on an single input field like total_matches I want to create a list which contains a list entry for each match

```
list_matches = ["match 1", "match 2", ....]
```

Not sure where to start. I thought of immediately printing them and then use some repeat print statement and use the input to create some count, but as I want to expand on the functions and I need them in a list. Also I hope to gain the skills to at some point swap the list for an actual list of matches with dates, etc.

so this is how I prompt for the amount of matches

```
total_matches = 0
total_matches= int(raw_input("Enter the amount of matches your team has to play: "))
```

Now I want to create a list where I expect something like

```
matches = ["match 1", "match 2", ....]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I know the post lacks detail, but unfortunately there was not much to add. I lacked the skills to give it a solid try. The anwser provided by @pistol2myhead worked for me and provides the list I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 3+, try this :

```
total_matches= int(input("Enter the amount of matches your team has to play: "))
matches = ['match '+str(k+1) for k in range(total_matches)]
```

For Python 2+, you need to change the way you take input from user. Rest is same.

```
total_matches= int(raw_input("Enter the amount of matches your team has to play: "))
```